# Mongoose update of embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm slowly going mad trying to understand how to update the value of an embedded document in mongoose, and written some node.js code which demonstrates the problem.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongoose_broken');

var ASchema = new Schema({
   value : { type: String, index: { unique: true } },
   bs    : [BSchema],
});
var BSchema = new Schema({
   value : { type: String },
});
var A = mongoose.model('A', ASchema);
var B = mongoose.model('B', BSchema);

// Add an entry of A, with 1 embedded B
//
var a = new A();
a.value = "hello";
var b = new B();
b.value = "world";
a.bs.push(b);

a.save(function(err) {
   if (err) {
      console.log("Error occured during first save() " + err);
      return;
   }

   // Now update a by changing a value inside the embedded b
   //
   A.findOne({ value: 'hello' }, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) { console.log("Error occured during find() " + err); return; }

      doc.bs[0].value = "moon";

      doc.save(function(err) {
         if (err) console.log("Error occuring during second save()");

         // Check b was updated?
         //
         if (doc.bs[0].value != "moon") {
            console.log ("b was not updated! (first check)");   
         } else {
            console.log ("b looks like it was updated (first check)");

            // Do a fresh find
            //
            A.findOne({value: "hello"}, function(err, doc_2) {
               if (err) { console.log("Error occured during second find() " + err); return; }

               if (doc_2.bs[0].value != "moon") {
                  console.log ("b was not updated! (second check)");   
               } else {
                  console.log ("b looks like it was updated (second check)");
               }
            });
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Output from running this is:

```
b looks like it was updated (first check)
b was not updated! (second check)
```

Any idea why the update of the embedded document is not saved?

Comment: If you do `console.log(doc_2.bs);` what does it say about doc_2

Comment: console.log(doc_2.bs) prints "[ [Object object] ]" and console.log(doc_2.bs[0]) gives "{ value: 'world', _id: 4f8ee35f8228240f43000002 }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare child schemas before using them in parents.

```
var BSchema = new Schema({
  value : { type: String },
});    
var ASchema = new Schema({
  value : { type: String, index: { unique: true } },
  bs    : [BSchema],
});
```

Comment: You got it - that fixed it. I would suggest its a bug though, because if you reference an non-existent Schema you get an error, but not when they're out of order... Pretty unexpected! Anyway i can sleep easy tonight knowing this is solved - Thanks Aaron :)

Comment: its a js thing called "hoisting" http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting